# Kotlin return back class instance in its method

Tags: class, kotlin, instance

I'm trying to make a class with method which modifies it's instance and returning it back.

```
class OUser {
    var name = ""
    var car = ""
    var city = ""


    operator fun get(param: String): String {
        return this[param]
    }


    operator fun set(param: String, value: String) {
        this[param] = value
    }


    fun fromData(data: HashMap<String, String>): OUser {
        this::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach {
            this[it.name] =  data[it.name]
        }
        return this
    }
}
```

But this results in infinite loop of calling itself.

The idea was to make possible to work with class in this way:

```
val data = hashMapOf<String, String>( "name" to "Alex", "car" to "BMW", "city" to "New York" )
val info: OUser = OUser().fromData(data)

val param = "name"
val name = info[param]
info[param] = "Bob"
```

What is the proper way to make this behaviour possible?

Comment: Getting elements from a map is probably the proper way. You can't expect to use your get method inside your get method, and it's worth it writing that code if you'll be able to use syntactic sugar later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start saying that I don't know why you want such a behavior when you have those properties as public `var`.

**Said that**, to make that behaviour possible, the solution is way more complicated than yours, because both the `operator fun` should access the class properties.

The comments I made will (hopefully) say it all:

```kotlin
class OUser {
    var name = ""
    var car = ""
    var city = ""

    // Cache the mutable String properties of this class to access them faster after.
    private val properties by lazy {
        this::class.declaredMemberProperties
            // We only care about mutable String properties.
            .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty1<OUser, String>>()
            // Map the property name to the property.
            .map { property -> property.name to property }
            .toMap()
    }

    operator fun get(param: String): String = properties.getValue(param).get(this)

    operator fun set(param: String, value: String) {
        properties.getValue(param).set(this, value)
    }

    fun fromData(data: HashMap<String, String>): OUser = apply {
        data.forEach { (param, value) ->
            // Invoke the "operator fun set" on each key-pair.
            this[param] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I want such behavior because I will need such classes with a lot more properties which will be accessed parametrically, so I wouldn't know exactly which of them would be looked to.
And further more this objects needed to be able to get values for their properties from several other different objects so I think making methods such as "fromData", "fromObjectTypeA", "fromObjectTypeB" would make things a bit easier.
Thanks for advice

Comment: It sounds like what you want is more like a Map than a class.